# Proving $b_1! \cdots b_k! < (b_1 + \cdots + b_k+1)!$

Tags: number-theory

I can't figure out how to solve this problem:

> Let $b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_k$ be positive integers with sum less than $n$. Prove that $$b_1!b_2! \cdots b_k! < n!.$$

Comment: sorry its a kind of maths question. but I found it in one of the graph theory topics and I am confused how to solve it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a pure math question, and so belongs in [math.se].

Comment: Expand the factorials into products on both sides. Try to map each factor on the left to a bigger factor on the right. Like $1\cdot 2 \, \cdot \, 1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4\,\cdot\, 1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 5 < 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot 6 \cdot 7 \cdot 8 \cdot 9 \cdot 10 \cdot 11 \cdot 12$.

Comment: you can probably do it by induction.

Comment: It might be helpful to identify the context where you encountered this task.  We discourage questions that simply state an exercise-style task out of context and expect us to solve it.  You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Answer (score 4):

The number of ways to divide a set of $b_1 + \cdots + b_k$ items into $k$ sets of sizes $b_1,\ldots,b_k$ is
$$
\frac{(b_1 + \cdots + b_k)!}{b_1! \cdots b_k!}.
$$
You take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

Show that if $0 < n ≤ m$ then $n!m! < (n-1)!(m+1)!$.

If $b_1 + b_2 + \dots + b_k = s$, use this to show that $b_1!b_2! \cdots b_k! < s!$ if there are at least two non-zero $b_i$. (Use induction over the sum of all but the largest element.)

Comparing to $(s+1)!$ makes the statement true even if there is only one non-zero $b_i$. If all $b_i$ are zero, it is false.